# not printing out all alphabet just one letter but it needs to print out every letter after the one that was entered

Tags: c++

so far it just prints out z after a but after a is b so i want it to print b c d e f g....z

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   char a = 'a';
   while (a < 'z')
   a++; 
  cout << a; 
}
```

im just looking for some help on how to do that then after that i need to enter 2 letters and do that with 2 letters but that is just for me i know this is not a code writing service just looking for some help on how to do that. thanks any help is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop, you need to enclose multiple statements in braces:

```
int main() 
{
    char a = 'a';
    while (a < 'z'){
        a++; 
        cout << a; 
    }
    cout << '\n'; // let's have a line break at the end
}
```

Otherwise the `cout` statement is only ran once the loop finishes.

**Sadly though this code is not portable** since the C++ standard mandates few requirements as to how the alpha characters are *encoded*. And their being contiguous and consecutive is not a requirement. The portable solution is based on the obvious if ostensibly puerile

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n";
}
```

; if you want to print all letters *from* a certain value, then use something on the lines of

```
int main() {
    const char* s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   
    char a = 'k'; // print from k onwards, for example
    for ( ; *s /*to prevent overrun*/ && *s != a; ++s);     
    std::cout << s; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to put the `cout` inside the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
   char a = 'a';
   while (a < 'z')
   {
      a++; 
      std::cout << a << " "; 
   }
}
```

Also added a space to distinguish the different letters. And removed the `using namespace std;` as it's not recommended.

Comment: a `std::cout << "\n"` at the end would be useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Only thing executed in while is a++; because there are no brackets surrounding statements that belongs to while. to do multiple statements surround them in brackets. Or like in this case its possible to make them into one statement.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char a = 'a';
    while (a < 'z')
        std::cout << ++a;
}
```

Comment: it won't print 'a' ;)

Comment: @YSC: My edit put the z in danger. This is too difficult for me to fix. I've rolled back.

Comment: Indeed! Their question is so difficult to parse in my brain I missed that. (I was answering to deleted comment from Haruki poiting out OP asked not to print the starting letter).

Comment: @YSC: It's fortunate then that you can play the portability card and write it out longhand ;-)

Comment: How about using list of chars including entire alphabet and breaking it once it reaches z? That would make it more portable.